# A Gaussian measure $\mu$ on $\mathcal{E}'(S^1)$ by Minlos theorem and its value for Sobolev spaces $H^{\alpha}(S^1)$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, schwartz-distributions, gaussian

I posted this question on ME as "[A Gaussian measure on $\mathcal{E}'(S^1)$ by Minlos Theorem and its value for $L^2(S^1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4798000/a-gaussian-measure-on-mathcales1-by-minlos-theorem-and-its-value-for-l)",
but it seems much more nontrivial than I expected... so, I post an extended version here.

Let $\mathcal{E}(S^1)$ be the space of smooth functions on the circle $S^1$ and denote its dual as $\mathcal{E}'(S^1)$.

Then, by the Minlos theorem, there exists a unique probability measure $\mu$ on $\mathcal{E}'(S^1)$ such that
\begin{equation}
e^{-\frac{1}{2}\lVert f \rVert^2_{L^2}}=\int_{\mathcal{E}'(S^1)} e^{iT(f)}d\mu(T)
\end{equation}
for all $f \in \mathcal{E}(S^1)$.

Also, we know that $\mathcal{E}(S^1) \subset H^{\alpha}(S^1) \subset \mathcal{E}'(S^1)$ for all $\alpha \in [0,\infty)$.

My question:
is it true that $\mu\bigl(H^{\alpha}(S^1) \bigr) \neq 0$ for any $\alpha \in [0,\infty)$? Also, can we get an exact value of $\mu\bigl(\mathcal{E}(S^1) \bigr)$?

Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand\al\alpha\newcommand\EE{\mathcal E}\newcommand\ip[2]{\langle #1,#2\rangle}$The answer is
$$\mu(\EE(S^1))=\mu(H^\al(S^1))=0$$
for all real $\al\ge0$.

Indeed, since $\EE(S^1))\subseteq H^\al(S^1)\subseteq H^0(S^1)=L^2(S^1)=:L^2$
for all real $\al\ge0$, it is enough to show that $\mu(L^2)=0$.

Let $X$ be a random vector in $\EE'(S^1)$ with distribution $\mu$. Let $(e_1,e_2,\dots)$ be an orthonormal basis of $L^2$, with $e_n\in\EE(S^1)$ for each $n$. Then $X_1:=X(e_1),X_2:=X(e_2),\dots$ are independent standard normal random variables and hence on the event $X\in L^2$ we have $\|X\|_{L^2}^2=\sum_{n=1}^\infty X_n^2=\infty$ almost surely (a.s.) -- say, by the strong law of large numbers.
So, $P(X\in L^2)=0$; that is, $\mu(L^2)=0$. $\quad\Box$

**Details on the latter two sentences:** By the strong law of large numbers, $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty X_n^2
=\lim_{N\to\infty}N\frac1N\,\sum_{n=1}^N X_n^2 \\ 
=\lim_{N\to\infty}N \; \lim_{N\to\infty}\frac1N\,\sum_{n=1}^N X_n^2
=\lim_{N\to\infty}N \times 1=\infty\text{ a.s.}$$

Introducing now the events $A:=\{X\in L^2\}$ and $B:=\{\sum_{n=1}^\infty X_n^2=\infty\}$, we see that $A\cap B=\emptyset$ and $P(B)=1$. So,
$$P(X\in L^2)=P(A) \\ 
=P(A\cap B)+P(A\setminus B)=0+0=0.$$

Comment: I do not understand. Why is the norm of $X$ necessarily infinite a.s.? If $X \in L^2$, then the norm must be finite.

Comment: @Isaac : As I said, by the strong law of large numbers: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty X_n^2=\lim_{N\to\infty}N\frac1N\,\sum_{n=1}^N X_n^2=\lim_{N\to\infty}N \lim_{N\to\infty}\frac1N\,\sum_{n=1}^N X_n^2=\lim_{N\to\infty}N \times 1=\infty$ almost surely.

Comment: But, how is the mean equal to $1$ for $L^2$? I think the mean is equal to $1$ only for $E'(S^1)$..

Comment: @Isaac : Consider the events $A:=\{X\in L^2\}$ and $B:=\{\sum_{n=1}^\infty X_n^2=\infty\}$. Then $A\cap B=\emptyset$ and $P(B)=1$. So, $P(X\in L^2)=P(A)=P(A\cap B)+P(A\setminus B)=0+0=0$.

Comment: I have came across the following question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/457725/extreme-confusion-with-the-exact-meaning-of-gaussian-measure-with-translation-i?noredirect=1#comment1185624_457725

Comment: I would be deeply grateful for any help from you.